# Why is ?publisher=4846312192 param added and indexed?

Tags: google-search, url-parameters

If you search google you will see ~37K indexed domains/pages using this exact same param.  I don't know where this param comes from.

What is causing this?

Comment: Are you seeing this with your own site? Curious, if I do a `site:` search on the top result, then none of _those_ URLs are returned. (?)

Comment: Interesting. Many (but not all) of these results also have "?publisher=4846312192" in their `title` element; if you change the URL, these sites display the changed string in their title, too.

Comment: i have seen this on a clients domain in webmaster tools, returning as a duplicate, which is not really an issue, since we can manage that, just found it very curious finding that many sites, with seemingly no relation are indexed with the exact same query string... the mystery continues ;)